# Why is the paragraph element not rendering the component's state on first load?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication

I have been breaking my head over this issue for the past 2-3 days. I am trying to show a new user's displayName set and stored on the Firebase Authentication database upon the load of their account page. I can not seem to get it showing upon the first load. I tried the setState way of doing it within the UserAccount component itself but it causes the same issue. The page needs to be manually refreshed for the username state to change and the p element to show the displayName in the screen. Please help me figure this out. Here's the code of the UserAccount component. If you need other codes from other components, please let me know.

```
class UserAccount extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            username: this.props.user.displayName

    }

    this.signout = this.signout.bind(this);

    }

    signout() {
        firebase.auth().signOut()
    }

   The following commented code is my first try to get the displayName to show but it had the same issue so I tried to pass the props from the App.js component to see if it would work but it again has the same issue:

 // componentDidMount () {

    //          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
    //          if (user) {
    //           var displayName = user.displayName;         
    //           console.log(displayName);
    //           this.setState((state) => {
    //             return {username: displayName} })
    //         } else {
    //           console.log('Please sig in')
    //         }
    //       })
    //         }


        render () {

        return (

                <div>

                <h1> You are in </h1>

                <button onClick={this.signout}>Sign Out</button>

                <p>Hey {this.state.username}</p>


                </div>


    )

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are using props value to initialize state in constructor. Since child component is already rendered, changing the parent prop doesn't call constructor of the child component. That's why it doesn't change the username and you need to forcefully trigger an update either by calling setState or forceUpdate. You can rather use **getDerivedStateFromProps** also as mentioned in above answer.

Otherwise, you can use react hooks useState and **useEffect** to fix this. By passing props as dependency for useEffect, component will be rendered each time prop changes.

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-mountain-2zqbn?file=/src/App.js:202-206

https://github.com/uberVU/react-guide/issues/17

Comment: Hi Vivekanand, thank you for your help. Unfortunately, your code did not work on my end. Not sure if it is the Firebase that is making the difference. I will send a GitHub link to all the code including the app.js component from the UserAccount component is served shortly. Hopefully, there is another solution to this. By the way, Ishaan's suggested code did not work either. I am at wits' end. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there, here's the link to the complete code on GitHub - https://github.com/DYT5131/dyt . I have also created an issue there. Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, one suggestion instead of using state in UserAccount component, try displaying props value in <p> tag. So, we can make sure whether the issue is in parent or child component.
`<p>Hey {this.props.user.displayName}</p>`

Comment: Hi Vivekanand, unfortunately, it did not work either. When I sign in, however, the displayName shows on first load but just not when I sign up. Hmmmm .... still thinking ....

Answer (score 0):

make sure the props has user.displayName, keep state.username == "" and try this:

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props,state){
      if(props.user.displayName !== state.username){
          state['username'] = props.user.displayName
          return state;
      }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ishaan, thank you so much for your help. Interestingly enough, right before I logged in here, I visited the react’s official website and read about the static getDerivedStateFromProps method and was going to try it. However, they also seem to discourage the reader from using it. What would be an alternative to using the props to show the user’s displayName in the UI on first load? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Ishaan, unfortunately, your suggested way of doing it did not work. UseEffects did not work either for some reason. I wonder if there is something wrong in the App.js from where the UserAccount is served. Here's a link to the complete code on GitHub - https://github.com/DYT5131/dyt. Please let me know what you think. Thanks.